# Return primitive values in OCMock

Tags: ios, primitive-types, ocmock

I tried the documentation: http://ocmock.org/reference/#argument-constraints and I can't make work to return any value different of 0

My code is working with:

```
    OCMStub([self.mockCurrentUser tipOptionSelected]).andReturn(0);
```

How can I do something like:

```
    OCMStub([self.mockCurrentUser tipOptionSelected]).andReturn(OCMOCK_VALUE([OCMArg isNotEqual:0]);
```

I want to that my stub return any Int except 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you misunderstood something. A stub (by definition) has to return a predefined value. The return value is programmed **behaviour** of the stub. The **matching** occurs on the arguments to determine whether the stub matches the invocation. This is also why they are called *argument* constraints.